# Как полностью отключить программу c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть программа, при запуске которой начинает выполняться много разных функций, и курсор начинает передвигаться по всему экрану, если программу закрыть через крестик, то она все равно продолжает работать и таскать курсор по экрану, как можно полностью остановить выполнение программы?

Comment: Из вопроса вообще непонятно: вы пытаетесь закрыть программу изнутри, из её собственного кода? Или вам нужно закрыть другое приложение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application.exit()`

> Сообщает всем потребителям сообщений, что они должны завершиться, а затем закрывает все окна приложения после того, как сообщения будут обработаны.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А если программа в неактивном состоянии находится, как её можно закрыть кнопкой?

Comment: Александр, какой кнопкой? Вешаете метод на необходимое вам событие и всё.

Comment: Они ведь не работают когда форма свернута или неактивна

Comment: Александр, давайте определимся с задачей, вопрос стоял как можно остановить выполнение программы?

Comment: Как закрыть вам сказали. Ваша задача теперь повесить таймер или какое-либо другое условие, которое будет приводить в исполнение вышеуказанный код. Более мягкий выход (если это главная форма) - это всё-таки `this.Close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант попробуйте:

```
Process.Kill();
```